# Найти каналы rgb из цвета HEX формата

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть цвет в HEX формате, например #ccff88, это не важно.

Как с помощью регулярных выражений взять первые две цифры, затем 3-ю и 4-ю, затем 5-ю и 6-ю.

Например, как мне приходится делать:

```
color = "#ccff00";
rgb=color.match(/w+/gi);
r=rgb[0]+rgb[1];
g=rgb[2]+rgb[3];
b=rgb[4]+rgb[5];
```

Существует какой-то простой способ, чтобы задать порядковый номер символа и его получить, а не изощряться потом с массивами, объектами и их преобразованиями?
Вроде:

```
color = "#ccff00";
r=color.match(/[1-й и 2-й символ]/gi);
g=color.match(/[3-й и 4-й символ]/gi);
b=color.match(/[5-й и 6-й символ]/gi);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function parseColor(c) {
  var match;
  
  if (match = c.match(/^#(..)(..)(..)$/) /* assignment */) {
    match = match.map(function (x) { return +('0x'+x) })
  } else if (match = c.match(/^#(.)(.)(.)$/) /* assignment */) {
    match = match.map(function (x) { return +('0x'+x+x) })
  }
  
  if (match) {
    return { r: match[1], g: match[2], b: match[3] };
  }
}

console.log(parseColor("#ccff88"));
console.log(parseColor("#cf8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, что Вам нужно.

Может быть это:

```
var string = "#ccff88";
alert( string[3] ); // вывели f
```

Comment: Я хочу узнать, есть ли возможность задать сразу в регулярном выражении, чтобы мне достал символы в диапазоне от такого, до такого. К примеру: есть `str = #ccff00`, я делаю так: `r=str.match(/[1,2]/g) `и получу `"сс"`, затем `g = str.match(/[3,4]/)g`, и аналогично по `b`. Как нибудь можно, чтобы не складывать потом символы. Какой-нибудь вариант проще

Comment: @Igor Я не понимаю зачем нужно регулярное выражение? var str = "#sdkihj";
alert(str.substr(1,2)); // получили sd

Comment: ! Еееее! Да именно это и мне и нужно было! Это и есть то самое простое решение которое мне нужно было! Хотя было интересно, можно ли регулярными что-то наподобие делать. Ну да ладно!)